# How to avoid precision loss when loading double type with more than 54 decimal places in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, double, precision

I am ascertaining whether spark accepts the extreme values Oracle's FLOAT(126) holds. I am loading 2^-126 which is the smallest float value into a Double Type column in spark dataframe. When reading from the dataframe, the decimal part is getting rounded off after 54 digits.

Please see the below code:

````
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame([(float(0.000000000000000000000000000000000000011754943508222875079687365372222456778186655567720875215087517062784172594547271728515625),)], ['flt_val']) ```

>>> df.printSchema()
root
 |-- flt_val: double (nullable = true)


>>> df.select(f.format_number(f.col('flt_val'), 126), 'flt_val').show(truncate=False)
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+
|format_number(flt_val, 126)                                                                                                     |flt_val               |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+
|0.000000000000000000000000000000000000011754943508222875000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000|1.1754943508222875E-38|
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+
````

As you can see both displaying the number as is and formatting the value are both losing the significant digits after `11754943508222875`.

How can I avoid this precision loss.

Comment: You could decide about the number of digits in each side of dot by `.cast(DoubleType())`.  DoubleType(int precision, int scale)

Comment: Certainly the precision loss is in the conversion of the `flt_val` into text and not in `flt_val` itself.  Perhaps  convert `flt_val` into a hex or binary output instead to determine its true value?

Comment: The 17 leading significant digits of 0.0000...11754943508222875... is enough to distinguish it from any other Double.  More non-zero digits are not _needed_ to disambiguate, even if more could  be printed to show its _exact_ value.

Comment: [Example](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/212490/function-to-print-a-double-exactly), the smallest `Double` needs 1000+ characters to print _exactly_, yet for all `Double`, sufficient to print to 17 _significant_ decimal places to round trip the text back to the original double.  You might not be able to prevent the printing with a conversion loss, but then you likely do not need more precision anyways to meet your higher level goals.